# How to use removeClass and addClass by click button

Tags: jquery, css

I want to highlight a button once it's clicked and add a particular class to a `<div>` having `class` `item` as well.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn gridLarge">largegrid</button>
<button type="button" class="btn grid active">smallgrid</button>
<button type="button" class="btn list">list</button>
<div class="item">text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item{
   height:240px;
   border:1px solid orange;
 }
.item.list{
   width:600px;
   height:500px;
   border:1px solid red;
 }
 .item.gird{
   width:400px;
   height:500px;
   border:1px solid red;
 }
.item.gridlarge{
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   border:1px solid red;
}

button{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid green;
   padding:20px;
  color:red;
  margin-bottom:20px;
 }

.btn.active{
  color:green;
  background-color:red;
}
```

**for example**

1. When `button.gridLarge` is clicked, I want to  highlight it (*By adding the class `active`*) and add the class `.gridLarge` to `div.item`
2. When `button.grid` is clicked, I want to  highlight it and add the class `.grid` to `div.item`
3. When `button.list` is clicked, I want to  highlight it and add the class `.list` to `div.item`

Here's the code i've so far: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/6UW33/)

Comment: __I should not have answered it.__ but here's something for you to play with  http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/XG6Jn/

Comment: yes sir.. but i also (.item) is addClass grid,list,largegrid..

Comment: you understand. i mean (.item )is Css class .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the class to be added as the `id` for buttons, you can do the following:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.item').removeClass().addClass('item').addClass(this.id);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6UW33/7/)

*side note: you had a typo in your css, the class in second button is `grid`, in css its `gird`*

Comment: That reminded me about setting `.active` class on clicked button and removing from formerly clicked.

Comment: Why not simple `removeClass()` instead of `attr('class',"")`?

Comment: @Satpal honestly because i didn't knew. I've only seen  using `attar('class',"")`.. thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `class` by `attr` and then remove `btn` class to get other `class` names. But, I would prefer to save class names in `data` attribute.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6UW33/5/)**

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" data-class="gridLarge" class="btn gridLarge active">largegrid</button>
<button type="button" data-class="grid" class="btn grid">smallgrid</button>
<button type="button" data-class="list" class="btn list">list</button>
<div class="item"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active');

    $('.item').removeClass('gridLarge grid list').addClass($this.data('class'));
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    height:240px;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
.item.list {
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.item.grid {
    width:400px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.item.gridlarge {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
button {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:20px;
    color:red;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.btn.active {
    color:green;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/straszak_piotr/6UW33/1/)

Best practice would be using `data-yourVariableName` (`data-class` in my DEMO) attributes for data that will be used by your code. Then you just write something like that:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".item").toggleClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
});
```

This is jQuery code. If it's unfamiliar to you, here's their [API](http://api.jquery.com/).